# How to get Excel to require user to allow macro else cannot open workbook?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

I have a macro in my Excel file that is meant to determine whether a user can open it or not. However, it seems like, depending on the settings of the user's machine, Excel by default disables the macro. This ended up opening and revealing the contents in the xls file.

How can I make sure that the user has to accept running the macro or Excel will close the workbook?

Comment: I don't see how. It would have to be without using VBA, since no VBA code will be run unless the user accepts running macros... I guess you can try to hide whatever is inside the file that you don't want to show and bring it up using the VBA code that runs when the macro is accepted?

Comment: http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/forcing-your-clients-to-enable-macros/

Comment: This is awesome, @Jean-FrançoisCorbett! I wish I would have seen that before typing it out myself!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATED** the code as it was not doing exactly what it was meant to...

This is pretty much the only way you can do this WITH a macro (thanks to @OlleSjögren for the insight :p)

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim Current As Worksheet
    Worksheets.Add(Before:=Worksheets(1)).Name = "Protection"
    Worksheets("Protection").Cells(1, 1) = "Please activate macros to view this workbook."

    For Each Current In Worksheets
        If Current.Name <> "Protection" Then
            Current.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
        End If
    Next Current


End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim Current As Worksheet

    For Each Current In Worksheets
         Current.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Next Current

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets("Protection").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

The property `xlSheetVeryHidden` means that it cannot be made visible through the UI (VBA code only can change it).

Comment: Thanks, I just tried this but it seems that clicking on the "Enable Macro" button doesn't trigger the Workbook_Open event because all the worksheets remain hidden.

Comment: I see, I will see what I can do.

Comment: Is the code placed inside the `ThisWorkbook` Excel Code Object? It's working just fine on my system; when I enable macros, it automatically runs the macro as if the workbook was just opened.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do it. But we can make a workaround.

1. First of all you need to hide all your worksheet and prevent user to unhide it. [Link](http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/01/22/hide-excel-worksheet-tab/). Following the link you will see that you can make a sheet *veryHidden*. As the link shows, you need to add a password to vba code too.
2. Then you can to create a macro that adds an InputBox with password

   ```
   Sub CheckPassword()
       Dim password As String

       password = InputBox("Enter the password")  'You can use a Form with Textbox [PasswordChar] to put ****
       If password = "myPass" Then
           Sheets(3).Visible = xlSheetVisible
           Sheets(3).Select
       End If
   End Sub
   ```
3. Finally you can attach a sub in the close event.

   ```
   Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
       Sheets(3).Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
   End Sub
   ```